# DNS round-robin requests not distributed evenly

Tags: domain-name-system, high-availability, a-record, round-robin

We have setup two DNS A records, where each points to a load balancer.

```
nslookup ourdomain.com

Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ourdomain.com
Address: 52.8.106.214
Name:   ourdomain.com
Address: 54.67.59.88
```

Upon benchmarking this setup, using Apache Bench `ab -n 5000 -c 5 http://ourdomain.com/`, I noticed that requests are **not evenly distributed** to both load balancers at all. Literally, most every request is sent to a single load balancer.

[image]

I was under the impression that round-robin DNS should distribute requests to both. Do I have something misconfigured?

Comment: Most people consider round-robin DNS a *poor man's* form of load balancing for a reason. Because of caching (by ISP's, resolvers and end-users) but also requests from networks behind proxy servers there is no guarantee that the actual load will distributed in any even fashion.

Comment: HBruijn is correct, but in addition you did not confirm whether or not you performed your test after the TTL of the `A` record you had changed expired. I would under no circumstances expect the traffic to be even (first record will probably win by a noticeable margin), but this is the type of split I would expect if the remote clients had the old version of that record in cache or if the second IP was nonroutable by some of the clients. Also ensure that the device you're running the load test on does not have a host file entry.

Comment: It's also entirely possible that the tool you're using does the DNS lookup once and then uses that IP address for the tests.